# Selenium (Java) refuses to find elements that are present on the page

Tags: java, html, selenium

I've got a page where Selenium is unable to find a  tag, but find other tags without any problems.

Markup:

```
<div id="dokumentkrav">
 <strong id="kravtype-Skatteoppgjør">Skatteoppgjør</strong><br>
 <span id="fornavn-etternavn"> Fornavn Etternavn </span>
</div>
```

(this is confirmed by inspecting the elements on the page)

Java/Selenium:

```
for (WebElement e : alleDokumentasjonskrav()) {
    String a = e.findElement(By.cssSelector("strong")).getText();
    String b = e.findElement(By.id("fornavn-ettenavn")).getText();
}

private List<WebElement> alleDokumentasjonskrav() {
    return driver.findElements(By.id("dokumentkrav"));
}
```

String a gets the text withing the  tags. (For specific reasons, the ID cannot be used here). This works like a charm.

But - String B gives the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#fornavn\-etternavn"}
```

I also tried finding String b with

```
String b = e.findElement(By.cssSelector("span")).getText();
```

to no avail.

I've also tried using waitForElementVisible() and waitForElementClickable() on the element. No help there either.

Any ideas? It's been a while since I've worked with Selenium, so I might be missing something essential here.

Comment: Is there any iframes, shadowroots?

Comment: Not that I can see, or know of. It's an Angular page, though.

Comment: Have you tried xPath?

Comment: I really, really don't link xpath if I can avoid it, due to it's lack of robustness.

Comment: Try using some waits maybe then due to page loads.

Comment: I've tried waitForElementVisible() and waitForElementClickable() on the element, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use some other library like for instance JSoup?
https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url

Comment: No, not yet. I thought I'd exhaust the "native" methods before I took that step.